# Can a business "change policy" and tack on extra fees for related services after a contract is agreed?

Tags: germany

If a business always bundles some service with another service which is necessary to use the first one, and informally contracts with a customer for the first service, can they later change their policy and charge the customer money for the second service?

For example, a cleaner brings their own supplies to clean customer's houses. This is the documented policy at the time a customer pre-pays for a year of weekly cleaning. 3 months later, the cleaner changes their policy and bills the customer extra for cleaning supplies, claiming the customer's pre-payment only covers the cleaning, not the supplies.

For example, when you buy internet access from your phone company, you'll have a physical phone line connection to access it, and the phone company agrees with this. This is the documented policy at the time a customer pre-pays for a year of internet access. 3 months later, the phone company changes their policy and bills the customer extra for the phone line, claiming that the customer's pre-payment only covers internet service, not a phone line.

For example, when you rent an apartment with no water meter, it's understood a reasonable use of water is included in the rent. This is the landlord's documented policy at the time a tenant pre-pays for a year of rent. 3 months later, the landlord installs a water meter and bills the tenant extra for water, claiming that the tenant's pre-payment only covers rent, not water. (maybe not the best hypothetical example since rental contracts are normally very precise)

Common sense says this is illegal. Which law or legal principle makes it illegal? Or is it actually legal?

Comment: My common sense says to read the small print of the contract, and that of the letter changing the conditions (e.g. whether it is actually a cancellation with a new contract offered). Rental is IMHO not a good example, the water should never be included in the rent, it's utilities (Nebenkosten), whether those are a lump sum or by meter doesn't matter - they are not rent.